# How to bulk edit in storyboard interface Builder document?

Tags: ios, storyboard

In my application I have more than 20 storyboard. Now I want to add safe area layout guide(iPhone X). Is there any way to bulk edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can select multiple `controllers` and change common properties. If you select the same type of control, say `UILabels`, you will be able to change ALL their properties at one time. If you select different `controls`, say a `UILabel` and a `UIImageView` and a `UIView`, you can change all of their common properties at one time.